# Show/hide specific links based on browser type

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, browser-detection

So I have a site that serves up a button to download a Chrome Extension. For any other browser than chrome or a mobile browser, it provides a different link. It seems to work, but the button loads rather slowly and some users have reported not even seeing the button.

So as a fall back I was thinking of just have a button load by default and if the javascript browser detection works have this default button hide.

HTML

```
<a href="http://goo.gl/1r8zjq" target="_blank" class="btn chrome-webstore">Get Betty for Gmail</a>                                
<a href="http://trybetty.com/mobile.html" target="_blank" class="mobile-other">Get Betty for Gmail</a>                               
<a href="http://trybetty.com/other-browser.html" target="_blank" class="desktop-other">Get Betty for Gmail</a>
<a onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install-button" class="chrome">Get Betty for Gmail</a>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function load(){
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Mobile|mobile/i.test(ua))
$('a.chrome-webstore').hide();
$('a.mobile-other').show();
else if (/Chrome/i.test(ua))
$('a.chrome-webstore').hide();
$('a.chrome').show();
else
$('a.chrome-webstore').hide();
$('a.desktop-other').show();
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
.mobile-other{
display: none;
}

.desktop-other{ 
display: none;
}

.chrome{ 
display: none;
}

.btn-1{ /* Orange */
background:#f38630;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wojo/v9sWb/

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: There are many pitfalls in attempting browser detection, but this may be a case in which it makes sense. Right off the bat, your logic is such that the `chrome-webstore` link is always hidden. In which case do you want to show that one?

Comment: Please try using `$()` i.e. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ to hide/display button. It should display at least one button as soon as user sees the page. As you are using `onload`, there will be some delay in executing `onload` event if you have images.